# How to scroll uitextview up when user touch it, in iPad app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6, uitextview

I am using `UITableView` and I have added `UITextView` in it.

I want to move the `UITableView` bit above the keypad.

Following is my code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

    NSCharacterSet *doneButtonCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSRange replacementTextRange = [text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:doneButtonCharacterSet];
    NSUInteger location = replacementTextRange.location;

    if (textView.text.length + text.length > 250){
        if (location != NSNotFound){
            //self.view.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
            [textView resignFirstResponder];

        }
        return NO;
    }
    else if (location != NSNotFound){
        //self.view.frame= CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+100, self.myTable.frame.size.width, self.myTable.frame.size.height);
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh. I have trimmed a number of your questions now, especially "please help me", which is chatty material that is not necessary. Some readers, furthermore, will interpret that sort of material as begging, since it is quite obvious you want help. It's also worth reading: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) - if you can specify accurately _what_ you need assistance with, that is often much better.

Comment: I also recommend using the preview window, so that you can see formatting problems before you publish, and please take note of people's edits to your material, so they do not have to keep correcting the same errors.

Comment: You need to give detail about your code. What is it doing now? What is expected? Which part is not working?